# Taking a variable from a ComboBox's content

Tags: java, swing, methods, combobox

I have a problem with the program that I want to create.
I'm a beginner at programming so could you please help me?

Well, I want to take the content of a `ComboBox` which is inside a `void` method and use it in an other Class.

Thats the ComboBox:
**
**
**

```
JComboBox ActionComboBox = new JComboBox();
ActionComboBox.addItem("Text");
ActionComboBox.addItem("text2");
ActionComboBox.addItem("text3");
ActionComboBox.setToolTipText("");
ActionComboBox.setBounds(253, 96, 103, 20);
frame.getContentPane().add(ActionComboBox);
```

**
**
**

I want to use the content of that `ComboBox` from a `void` method, at a method in another class I use that code to do that:

(I also Import (the name of the class))

**
**

```
private String Action()
{
        String actionBox = ActionComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        return actionBox;
}
```

**
**

Well, the program says that::  `ActionComboBox` cannot be resolved! 
as an error.

What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish your task, you'll need to follow the steps below.

First, make the line of code below global to the containing class:

```
JComboBox ActionComboBox = new JComboBox();
```

Second, create a `getter` method for the `ActionComboBox`:

```
public JComboBox getActionComboBox(){
       return ActionComboBox;
}
```

then in your **other** class you can use the `getter` method to access a reference to the `ActionComboBox`.

Example, this:

```
String actionBox = ActionComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

would become this:

```
String actionBox = someInstanceName.getActionComboBox().getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: oh thank you mate you helped me a lot!

you also helped me to understand some thing :)